# Visual Studio SqlException was unhandled: Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have a very simple Windows Form. I want to add data to a database by using it.

In my C# winforms solution, I created a data source named **db_studentDataSet** and connected my database **db_student**. Whenever I run my solution, I get the following exception:

```
SqlException was unhandled: Login failed for user 'sa'
```

Here's my code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimpleEnrollmentSystem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.studentsBindingSource.EndEdit();
            studentsTableAdapter.Insert("Ahmed", "Rownak", "Male", 13, "Malibagh");
        }
    }  

}
```

Here's a image of my form:

[image: MyForm]

Here's my database:

```
  CREATE TABLE Students
  (
      StudentID int primary key,
      FirstName string,
      LastName string,
      Gender string,
      Age int,
      Address string 
  )
```

Note that I've only coded for the **Add** button functionality.

What is wrong with my code? Or is it anything else? Maybe the way I'm trying to achieve this is wrong? Is there a better way, in that case?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and SQL Server 2012 Express Edition.

**EDIT - 1:** I have changed my buttonAdd_Click() method.

```
  private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAADMAAN;Initial Catalog=db_student;User ID=sa;Password=***********");
      con1.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Students(StudentID, FirstName, LastName, Gender, Age, Address) VALUES('" + studentIDTextBox.Text + "','" + firstNameTextBox.Text + "','" + lastNameTextBox.Text + "','" + genderTextBox.Text + "','" + ageTextBox.Text + "','" + addressTextBox.Text +"')",con1);
      cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con1.Close();

  }
```

Comment: Don't you think that it may be wrong login / pass? ;)

Comment: UserName and Password is correct as far as I know.

Comment: `Login failed for user 'sa'` suggests it's not correct. How do you log directly into the database? And are you sure you try to reach the correct DB on the correct server?

Comment: Problem with code? None. Problem with username? Lots: its seriously weak for a database username. Personally, remake your username and type it correctly

Comment: `sa` is the default sysadmin user. Don't use it for your application. The login failure could also be because the `sa` user is disabled (although I believe the error may be different, not really sure).

Comment: I have SQL Server 2012 mixed mode installed. I give my username and password and log in.

Comment: Well, here's my connectionstring: Data Source=SAADMAAN;Initial Catalog=db_student;User ID=sa;Password=***********

Comment: does that same username and pwd work if you try to connect for example in SQL management studio?

Comment: Yes. This username and pwd works when I connect in Management System.

Comment: Have you tried using Windows Authentication instead? Why do you have to use SQL Authentication?

Comment: I have always been using SQL Authentication in while logging in to my databse in Management System. That's why I preferred SQL Authentication while adding the data source.

Comment: have you tried giving the password in clear text?

Comment: @Kiran My bad ... ... I totally forgot. Thanks a lot. It's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to user Kiran Hegde's suggestion, I changed the password into clear text in my connection string.

```
  SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAADMAAN;Initial Catalog=db_student;User ID=sa;Password=open");
```

That solved the problem. So silly of me, I skipped this obvious thing.